# Icon not showing on moving tabbed toolbar placement to the bottom in Xamarin C# android, it worked before adding the bottom transfer code

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

Before adding this code to transfer my navigation toolbar placement to the bottom
`xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"`
The icons were showing at the top but now, they are just blanks and not showing
[image]

what do I need to add or modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution1:**

You could use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=add_circle&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_add_circle&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6)) to get tthe matching tabbar icon's resolutions.

Choose the image in Source. Upload your icon. And then download the zip for all resolutions.

The Tab1 show the matching icon.

**Solution2:**

You could use Shell tabs directly.

For more details, please refer to the MS docus.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs

Comment: so my icons were just out of scale with the resolution?

Comment: Mostly it caused by the resolution.  Normaly, this way works well.

Comment: thank you so much for this Wendy, I'm just starting with Xamarin.